# 2D Kinematics and Projectile Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

In [this page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11765177/3.6%20-%20Projectile%20Motion.pdf), I have finished most of the problems. Some of them I am unable to figure out.

For 3 a-j, is it possible to solve this problem given parts a and b, that is, can I solve these problems in order a-j with no problem?

Can I do this whole sheet using only 3 formulas?
v^2 = v0^2 + 2a delta x
delta x = v0 t + 1/2 a t^2
v = v0 + at

I managed to solve 3 a and b correctly. 69.282 and 40. However I am not sure how to implement the formulas for part c. I can somewhat figure out i and j and some others but I want to work on part c.

For question 8, it asks for the angles. I literally have no idea how to approach the problem. How can I do it?

I understand this is literally how not to ask a hw question but I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: *"I understand this is literally how not to ask a hw question"*...really? You are aware that we do not want such questions and you *deliberately* ignore that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes. I apologize. (brutal honesty here)

Comment: @RegisteredUser: you've got a 109 rep and should know better than to ask *'can you do this for me?'* type questions. Flagged.

Comment: @Gert Ouch. I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: withdraw would be better, despite the rules this site is *inundated* with homework.

Comment: @Gert Other sites clearly hate homework questions. I'm currently reading highly upvoted homework questions on physics.SE

Comment: @Gert I'm going to delete the question in a few min.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: keep telling yourself that. You do realise that when this 'question' gets deleted the answerer will also lose his credits earned, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30759/discussion-between-registered-user-and-gert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints:

3c,d,e) The projectile will be at its highest point when the vertical component of its velocity is zero. (Otherwise, it would be going up towards or coming down from a higher point.)

f,g) You should be able to see that f) is the same as e). Try to work it out with the formulas before plugging numbers in, if you can't. g) exhibits a similar symmetry.

h,i) This is the same as question 2.

j) You can answer this one if you can answer i).

Remember that the formulas you have up there apply in both the x and y directions. It looks like you already know how to break up a vector into its components so you should have no problems.

For question 8, think about it physically. The water travels in projectile motion just like a ball thrown in the air. Think about where a ball would land if you throw it at the same speed but different angles between 0 and 90 degrees.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I would like ask one more quick question. in #6, would delta y account for the y component? i.e. 20 + V0y?